# how to use map in javascript inside an object which contain objects with object name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a javascript object which I receive from a axios response.
I want to perform map inside my data in the quote field of my object and get the names of the object inside the 'quote' object.

I want the name inside the 'quote'.

How can I perform map and get USD,BTC,BCH,ETH,LTC,XRP

Here is my response object received from  axios:

[image]

The data is store at `this.state.data`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 Also, please use proper upper and lower case in your text to aid readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the object you displayed is stored in `data`. Then you can do something like this to get an array of `quote` names

```
let quoteNames = Object.keys(data.quote);
```

Hope this works for you.